# Joining similar pandas DataFrame columns, ordering them and filling wth np.NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I am trying to join several DataFrame objects with one column each that have similar string values. I want the output to be a single DataFrame with the string values ordered alphabetically and missing values from other columns to be filled with np.NaN.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

The dataframes

```
list1 = [{'1':'APA'}, {'1':'HBO'}, {'1': 'JRC'}]
list2 = [{'2':'ABC'}, {'2':'HBO'}, {'2': 'JRC'}, {'2':'XYZ'}]
list3 = [{'3':'QRS'}, {'3':'XYZ'}]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(list3)
```

These look like this:

df1

```
     1
0  APA
1  HBO
2  JRC
```

df2

```
     2
0  ABC
1  HBO
2  JRC
3  XYZ
```

df3

```
     3
0  QRS
1  XYZ
```

I would like the final output to look like this:

df_join

```
     1    2    3
0  NaN  ABC  NaN
1  APA  NaN  NaN
2  HBO  HBO  NaN
3  JRC  JRC  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  QRS
5  NaN  XYZ  XYZ
```

I have tried using two `outer join` operations but this simply puts the `NaN`s at the beginning or end of each column. Please let me know if you have any advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set ***all*** the indexes!! <sub>(This might be really slow)</sub>.  `np.unique` takes care of the alphabetic sorting.

---

```
def f(df, total):
    return df.set_index(df.iloc[:, 0]).reindex(total)

un = np.unique(np.concatenate((df1.values, df2.values, df3.values)))

pd.concat([*map(f, [df1, df2, df3], (un,)*3)], axis=1).reset_index(drop=1)
```

```
     1    2    3
0  NaN  ABC  NaN
1  APA  NaN  NaN
2  HBO  HBO  NaN
3  JRC  JRC  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  QRS
5  NaN  XYZ  XYZ
```